# How can I integrate Visual Studio 2010 with DotNetNuke Community Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dotnetnuke

How can I integrate visual studio 2010 with DotNetNuke Community Edition?
Please explain it to me clearly

Answer (score 2):

You will need to be building DNNModules. A guide on how to get going can be found here:

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Module-Development.aspx

There is also a prebuilt DNNModule template which someone has developed here:

http://dnnmodule.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have module development templates for VS2010 on Codeplex at http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/releases/view/93348. The newer releases of the project are for VS2012.

In DNN development you will typically not open the DNN solution itself, but individual projects for modules and skins. This way you create and work with extensions for the platform, but not modify the platform itself.

You can open the DNN solution if you wish to make changes to it, but you should be careful making changes as you will end up going down your own fork and have difficulty when you want to upgrade to a new version of DNN.